# Why map or reduce keeps running without any condition given?

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration, reduce, higher-order-functions

```
const array = [7, 2, 4, 1, 10, 6, 5, 11]

const max = array.reduce((acc, val) => {
    console.log(val, acc)
    
    return val > acc ? val : acc
}, 0)

console.log(max)
```

I was looking at this code of reduce array method, one thing I couldn't understand at all is, How the reducer function is going to the next iteration? There is no condition that forces the reducer function to go to the next element in the array. In the first iteration, the val is 7, the first element of the array, and acc is 0, the reducer function returns 7 as per the condition written.
My question is how the number 7 as being the new accumulator is going to be called on the reducer function. I thought the normal procedure is you have to meet some kind of condition to iterate over again and again. Is there something written in the reduce method itself? Can you explain me please?

Comment: That was not my question. @cmgchess

Comment: _"I thought the normal procedure is you have to meet some kind of condition to iterate over again and again"_ - no, you don't need to meet a particular condition for the next iteration to occur (unlike you do with a `while` loop or `for` loop). Reduce will loop through all elements unless it's explicitly stopped (such as by using `throw` within the callback)

Comment: @cmgchess "it is iterating because you have a return statement." ~ Can you please explain it with a little bit more words?

Comment: @ToufiqurRahman, it will iterating whatever except you force it to stop, you could think `array.reduce` like`array.map` or `array.forEach` which will iterating the whole array, but the goal of `array.reduce` is to output single result. I dont't think if you don't have return statement it won't work, but it will not work as the orginal goal of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `array.reduce`:

> reduce
> calls the callback, as a function, once for each element after the
> first element present in the array, in ascending order.

You could understand the `reduce` as a `array.map` but the goal of it is to change the array to a singe output.

It will loop over the whole `array` same with the `forEach`/`map`/...

Check below example, even though you don't do anything, like `return` or anything else to `array.reduce`, it will still work and iterate the `array`

You could check here for [more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

But of course if you don't use `return` for `array.reduce`, there will be no benefit for you to use array.reduce

```js
const array = [7, 2, 4, 1, 10, 6, 5, 11]

const max = array.reduce((acc, val) => {
  console.log(val)
}, 0)

console.log(max)
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

The reduce() method executes a user-supplied “reducer” callback function on *each* element of the array,

Answer (score 0):

The `reduce` method's implementation resembles something like this:

```
Array.prototype.reduce = function(callback, initialValue) {
    var acc = initialValue;
    for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        acc = callback(acc, this[i], i);
    }
    return acc;
}
```

The `reduce` methods *iteration condition* is the array length.
The same goes for `map`.